# error when trying to mv a file with -r in the name of the file

Tags: bash

Here is my problem :

I have a file with -r in the name: `-r.jpg`

When I tried to do a `mv *.jpg old/` I get:

```
mv: invalid option -- 'r'
```

Even for

```
for g in *.jpg;do echo $g &&mv "${g}" old/;done
```

I have the same error.

Comment: Use `mv -- *.jpg old/`, `--` disables all additional "parameters" after `--`.

Comment: It's a good thing that you didn't try to `rm` a file that includes `-rf` ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most command-line utilities have a provision to separate *options* from *arguments*.

That prevents a multitude of problems with *"special"* file names that look like options.

The most common separator indication the end of the options is two hyphens `--` or <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> which is also supported by `mv`.

In other words:

```
 mv [OPTIONS] -- SOURCE DEST
```

or since you didn't specify any options:

```
 mv -- *.jpg old/
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to prepend the filename with the `./` describing the relative path

```sh
for g in *.jpg; do echo $g && mv "./${g}" old/; done
```

It is also possible to use the absolute path

```
for g in $(pwd)/*.jpg; do echo $g && mv $g old/; done
```

Alternatively, you may want to use the `find` command as it already provides the relative path ( you can use the `--max-depth` if you want to process only the current directory )

```
for g in $(find . -name "*jpg"); do mv $g old; done
```

And in the worst case whereby you have many complex un-parsable characters, you can refer to the inode numbers combined with the `find -inum` and process your files accordingly

```
 $ for g in $(ls -i1 ./*jpg | cut -f1 -d' '); do find . -inum $g -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' old; done
```

Comment: using "./" is a clever hint ; and the inum hint a very good solution :)

Comment: There's literally no "unparsable" characters: All you need to do is to quote variables properly. In most cases a pair of double quotes suffices.

Comment: `mv ./*.jpg   old/` would work; you don't need to loop one file at a time.

Comment: @Bussiere: The `find -inum` hack is not particularly useful unless you want to find hard links.   `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t old/` or something like that will do the same thing, and eventually run `mv -t old ./-r.jpg`, like this command.  (Possibly with multiple other filenames on the same command line).  It just wastes a lot of time starting `find` to scan the whole subtree for files with that inode number for each input file, then printing the filename.  It's *not* running `mv` on the inode number; Unix system-calls can't do that.

Comment: @Bussiere: The key thing that makes it work (`./*.jpg` instead of `*.jpg`) is already used on the `ls` command line to avoid running `ls -r.jpg`, the rest is just wasted effort.  I can't picture a case where having find look for an inode number is better than just using find's own filename matching like `-iname` or `-path`, and ideally using `-exec mv -t old/ {} +` to avoid even needing xargs.